# Component won't render on setState, always redirects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I am trying to render a component based on authentication. If the user is not authenticated, he is redirected to the login page.

No matter what I do, If I directly go to the `/` route, the login component keeps getting rendered.

I can't render the dashboard, even if `isAuthenticated` is true and the view re-renders. What am I doing wrong? Is it something with the promise?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super()
        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.authenticate()
    }
    authenticate(){
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/authenticated", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                token: localStorage.getItem("token")
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data.success){
                this.setState({             // Re-render
                    isAuthenticated: true
                })
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                <div id="container">
                    // First time false. After setState it's true.
                    {console.log("render", this.state.isAuthenticated)}

                    <Route exact path="/" render={() => {
                        // First time false. After setState, doesn't log.
                        console.log("auth", this.state.isAuthenticated);

                        return this.state.isAuthenticated
                        ? <Dashboard />
                        : <Redirect to="/login"/>
                    }}/>

                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you reload the page you're back to your initial state.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't know how to structure my code to accomplish my goal. Can you please give me a hint? Do I need to fetch the state, instead of hard coding it?

Comment: `componentDidUpdate()` happens only after the first render, so the first render's `this.state.isAuthenticated` is always `false`, therefore you always get the redirect. You need a 3 way toggle, maybe `true`, `false` and `undefined`, and set the initial state to `undefined`.

Comment: If you make a CodeSandbox example I'll fix it for you.